# How to compare Result to .succeed in swift

Tags: swift

From https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/161/how-to-use-result-in-swift, it has example about how to use 'Result in swift', like this:

```
fetchUnreadCount1(from: "https://www.hackingwithswift.com") { result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let count):
        print("\(count) unread messages.")
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

my question is which the above switch case works, why this does not compile:

```
 if (result == .success) {
     print ("Success")
 }
```

I get error saying Cannot convert value of type

> 'Result<Void, Error>' to expected argument type
> 'DispatchTimeoutResult'

Comment: I'm not sure about the error reason but to check a condition with an enum having an associated value you have to use switch.

Comment: You can use `if case` in this situation, `if case .success(let count) = result {` and then use the `count` variable in the `if` clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [pattern matching](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Patterns.html) in `if` statement with `case` like this:

```
if case .success = result {
    print("Success")
}
```